# Tkinter Text and Itemconfigure Memory Leak

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, memory-leaks, tkinter

**Background:**
A few months ago, I posted here asking about a memory leak occurring in my Tkinter canvas class. The primary cause of this was an accidental loop over several key bindings, and the removal of these bindings largely alleviated my problem. However, there remained a small memory leak, but I disregarded it as negligible enough to ignore. At this point (after a couple more months of work), the previously small leak has grown to be potentially damaging -- after an hour of continuous use my program can now fill 800mb+ of system memory, which is a serious concern as without the leak, the program should only require ~60mb.

**The Issue:**
After some testing, I have narrowed the origin down to two causes:
1. Tkinter itemconfigure function 
2. Tkinter text objects 
The code snippet below recreates the issue on my machine.

```
from Tkinter import *

stop=0

class Interface:
    def Initialise(self,master):
        global x
        self.master=master
        x=50
        width,height=master.winfo_screenwidth(),master.winfo_screenheight()  
        self.c=Canvas(self.master, width=width, height=height, bg='white',scrollregion=(-1500,-1500,10000,10000))
        self.c.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
        self.Regenerate()
        self.master.bind("<a>", self.auto)

    def Regenerate(self):
        self.G=UI_Canvas()
        self.G.Visualise(self.c,x)

    def auto(self, event):
        global stop
        stop+=1
        self.master.after(5, self.auto_rotate)

    def auto_rotate(self):
        global x
        if stop % 2 == 1:
            x+=0.1
            self.Regenerate()
            self.c.after(5, self.auto_rotate)

class UI_Canvas:
    def Visualise(self, canvas,x):

        self.canvas=canvas
        self.canvas.delete('Network')

        data=[((x,400,0),1),((x,450,0),2),((x+50,450,0),3),((x+50,400,0),4)] 
        for (x,y,z), j in data:
            self.canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5, fill='gray15', tags=(j,("Node %.5s" % j),'Network'))
            #self.canvas.create_text(x-10,y, text=(j), fill='black', font=('Helvetica',12), tags=(j, ("Node %.5s" % j), 'Network'))

root=Tk()
UI=Interface()
UI.Initialise(root)
root.mainloop()
```

By commenting out all text and itemconfigure objects, the leak disappears and the program runs at a constant memory usage (as required). Specifically, commenting out all text objects (leaving no objects to be configured), removes the leak, and it therefore seems to me that the repeated refresh of text on-screen is causing the leak. Other canvas objects (lines, ovals and polygons) that I use do not cause this issue.
**Attempted Solutions**
Other memory leak problems posted here seem to revolve around having updates within loops, but I have not relied on this method, and instead delete then re-create objects inside a loop. As previously mentioned, this method works fine with shapes, but apparently not with text. I have moved the text object code into my 'master' canvas class (thereby no longer being directly in a refresh loop), and instead attempted to configure it from the loop, but the issue persists.
**Question**
The information contained in these text objects is very important to easily using my program, and resolving this issue is essential. My questions are: what is causing this issue? And are there any possible solutions?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Please post a minimal code that can be run.

Comment: I've updated the snippet in the question to now be a standalone code. This code generates the issue on my machine/s.

Comment: Fixed indentations and replaced `screenwidth` with `width`.

Comment: I ran your code (uncomment the `create_text` line, pressed `a` key after the program started) about 5 minutes. Memory usage did not increased. (Windows 7 + Python 2.7.6 64bit). http://i.imgur.com/1aQAirE.png

Comment: That's odd, I just ran it again (Mac OSX 10.9.2, Python 2.7.8), 2 minutes without pressing 'a' and there was no change, ran for 2 minutes and it increased from 13mb to 16.2mb, and from experience with the 'full' program, this increase is proportional to the quantity of on-screen text. I will attempt to run it on a Win7 workstation later.

Comment: BTW, there's no `itemconfigure` in the code.

Comment: I removed it to keep the code short, although and this code better frames my issue I feel.

Comment: In ubuntu 13.10, Python 2.7.5 64bit, memory usage does not increased (12MB, ran about 10min.)

Comment: Perhaps its a Mac OSX issue? I'm about to head to a Win7 workstation to check it out, I ran the program for ~15 minutes and it rose from 13mb to 26.5mb.

Comment: Are you sure you run above script you posted?

Comment: Yes, I have literally copied and pasted the above code... I have now run the above on a Win7 workstation and on this machine it is now showing no increase. That's indicative of an issue with Mac OSX perhaps? In which case there's not much to be done I guess